# Magento Template design

Tags: magento

In my magento template i has been used following code "getChildHtml('content')" in my home page. Where it load the content using getChildHtml() from template file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find your global structure of your page in page.xml. For example if you can use 3 colums

```
<default translate="label" module="page">
    <label>All Pages</label>
    <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml" template="page/3columns.phtml">
....
```

then, in the template page/3columns.phtml of your design theme you can see this phtml and into it you can see this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>" lang="<?php echo $this->getLang() ?>">
<head>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('head') ?>
</head>
<body<?php echo $this->getBodyClass()?' class="'.$this->getBodyClass().'"':'' ?>>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('after_body_start') ?>
<div class="wrapper">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_notices') ?>
    <div class="page">
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>
        <div class="main-container col3-layout">
            <div class="main">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
                <div class="col-wrapper">
                    <div class="col-main">
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-left sidebar"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('left') ?></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-right sidebar"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('right') ?></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('before_body_end') ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php echo $this->getAbsoluteFooter() ?>
</body>
</html>
```

with the getChildHtml('content') ?>.
Is this resolve your question?

Comment: Yes My problem has been fixed with help of your Code.Thanks

Comment: I have another one question.Can you explain me difference between Mage::getModel() and Mage::getSingleton() in magento collection loading.

Comment: This is a design patern, in Magento you have many of this. Whit Mage::getSingleton() you be sure that the instance ob the object is unique, Example: Mage::getSingleton('customer/session'). you want the original objet, to retrieve the session active actually, whit Mage::getModel() you instance a new Object in the call. But you can put a new question. I am ready to answer it :P